# Dynamic .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I am creating a modular CMS using the codeigniter framework, the main asset directory is:

`/public/assets/[admin|public]/[css|images|js]`

my current htaccess routes everything except requests starting with 'public' to the index.php file.

The new module system allows each module to have its own assets which would be located at

```
application/modules/*SOME_MODULE*/assets/[admin|public]/[css|images|js]
```

my question is, is it possible to create a rule to stop anything from a modules asset directory being routed to index.php?

My Current .httacces is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public/*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CI-Playground/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you describe the directory structure a little more, as far as where the `.htaccess` file is in relationship to the `public/` and `application/` directories?

Comment: See Attached a screenshot of my directory structure, highlighted are the root .htaccess and one of my module's assets folder: http://cl.ly/26jG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your URLs would be the full path to the modules' various assets directories, you could easily exclude them from being rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public/)
RewriteCond $0 !^application/modules/[^/]+/assets/(admin|public)/(css|images|js)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /CI-Playground/index.php/$1 [L]
```

You might like to cut out the `application/modules` part to make your request path shorter and your directory structure less exposed, which you could do like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public/)
RewriteCond $0 !^[^/]+/assets/(admin|public)/(css|images|js)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /CI-Playground/index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/assets/(admin|public)/(css|images|js).*$ application/modules/$0
```

I see that you have another `.htaccess` in your application directory though, which you'll need to check for anything that might prevent outside requests from reaching the modules' files.